# Import data to MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql

I have a database with 6 tables, and I want to import these tables to an **existing** database within MySQL Workbench.

I used phpMyAdmin to export the database to a `.sql` file, and imported it to MySQL Workbench using "Data Import/Restore" button, but nothing happened(I don't know where this file is now in MySQL Workbench, I did get an import success message, but where exactly did this database go?). Then I tried a `.CSV` file, but it doesn't seem to work because it also saved the entire database, and MySQL Workbench expects only separate tables(Or not?)

Do I have to create each table separately and import data to each table individually?

Or, there is a better way to copy database content to an existing database in MySQL Workbench?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use MySQL Workbench to import into an existing schema.

**Server -> Data Import -> Import from self-contained file -> Default Target Schema**

[image]

Comment: I did exactly that, import was successful, still my database is empty

Comment: Can you check if the .sql file that is being imported has the SQL statements to create tables and insert data in them?

Comment: Yes it does I just checked to make sure

Comment: What does MySQLWorkbench output in log once the import has finished?

Comment: That's weird, I just tried to import again to see the log (Because I don't know where the logs were saved) And this time it tells me that the tables already exist, and it failed with exit code 1. So if the tables exist, why can't I see them?

Comment: I assume you are able to see the schema under which the tables were created on the left-hand side panel under 'SCHEMAS'. Try right-clicking the schema and click 'Refresh All'.

Comment: Thank you, I guess that would've worked as well, instead of refreshing I just logged in and out, so it's solved now

Answer (score 1):

1. Check whether your exported file has only data or both structure and data. If your exported file only contain data, then check the point 3
   In MySQL Workbench, we can easily export with both Structure and Data. Check the attached screenshot:

[image: how to export database using workbench]

2. If you have already exported your database with proper format, then here's few point you need to consider before you import a file using MySQL Workbench

- If you want to import to a new database, then you have to create a new database inside your database connection or workbench connection.
- If you want to use an already existing database, then no need to create a new one.
- In workbench select the database, please check attached the screenshot

[image: how to import database using workbench]

3. If you exported database only contains data, then you have to create all the tables inside your new database.

Answer (score 0):

while exporting  your phpmyadmin database use the Custom - display all possible options