# Mysql Workbench import data SQL error 1142

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, data-import

I had a DB with some values and for some reasons I had to clear the content of all tables. Then I changed the structure of my tables and I wanted to add the new data to populate my tables.

In order to add the data I do basically like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50164913/import-data-to-mysql-workbench). Here is what I get, I saw on the internet that it was a problem with my version on Mysql workbench but I never had any problem when I did that previously so I'm kinda not sure where is the real problem.

[image: Cant add data]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I get the error, it definitely was not a MySQL version.